# ArrayList to HashMap with (key, Array)

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, dictionary

Okay, so I have seen a lot of questions on this topic, to convert an ArrayList to a HashMap where the value is not an array. I have also seen some where the value is an array but then the sizes need to be identical which is not the case in the problem I am trying to solve.

I have something like this:

```
public static List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
public Map<String, User[]> playersList = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, User[]>(1000);

//then X number of users into user List
userList.add(new User(1, "alex"));
userList.add(new User(2, "mangiA"));
userList.add(new User(3, "filipe"));
userList.add(new User(4, "joh32Ac"));
userList.add(new User(5, "s7HKO"));
```

What I need to create is playersList like this one:

```
User[] ur = {u1,u2};
String nick1 = ""; String nick2="";
            
if (u1!=null){
    nick1=u1.getNickname();
}
            
if (u2!=null){
    nick2=u2.getNickname();
}
            
playersList.put(nick1+" vs "+nick2, ur);
```

**So the final result should be when I print the keys:**

> alex vs mangiA
>
> filipe vs john32Ac
>
> s7HKO vs

When new user is added to the list of-course s7HKO should get his pair so the result:

> alex vs mangiA
>
> filipe vs john32Ac
>
> s7HKO vs thatNewUserNickName

I have tried several solutions, but without success. All input from your side will be much appreciated!

Comment: To me it seems better to create a type of object to encapsulate the `String, User[]` data. Maybe a `Match` which has 2 users and a given description? Then you can just list the matches.

Comment: Well.. I need real time indicators here so I need that situation with incomplete pair... User1 vs "" When I have pairs code which I wrote can work somehow

Comment: then why not set the other user null? They wouldn't be set in stone.

Comment: I set it to null in array as well.. Sorry for not getting you idea the best way. Can you maybe share some snippet ?